# Modify a delimited string with unknown length of chars in python

Tags: python, string, delimiter

I have some string for example:
`Temperature|day|54|23|5453|656|0|...|45`
I loop for checking that the numbers are bigger than 0:
If one is equal to 0 change it to 999 like this: 
`Temperature|day|54|23|5453|656|999|...|45`.
How can I make it?

Comment: Questions asking for help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [ask] and [edit] your post - preferable with a [mre] and an explanation what went awry. Thanks.

Comment: `str.split('|')[2:]` check in this list now ;) Make sure to convert the elements into `int` before checking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Let say you string is declared with name a

```
b = a.split('|')

for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i] == '0':
        b[i] = '999'

result = '|'.join(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that

```
your_list = your_string.split('|')
for index, val in enumerate(your_list):
   if val == '0':
      your_list[index] = '999'

result = '|'.join(your_list)
```

Comment: you are comparing a string `val` against a number `0` - wich will never be equal. Alwys check your answers in a python environment - f.e. http://pyfiddle.io beside that your solution is not exactly the same as Dhavals and adds nothing new